# Given two variables, find their distance(in bytes) in the computer’s brain(memory)

Tags: pointers

Can someone please explain how the code below works to find the distance in bytes between two variable in memory?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 5;
    int b = 10;
    int difn = (int)(&b) - (int)(&a);
   
    if(difn < 0) difn *= -1;

    printf("Difference in bytes: %d\n", difn);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`&` operator return byte address in memory. Thus if you subtract two byte addresses you get byte difference between those addresses. Since this difference can be negative, you need to check if it is and if so multiply it by -1 (absolute value). Then you just print it out.

Comment: int difn = (int)(&b) - (int)(&a);

in here if I delete  the int in both cases the result is 1 but if I don't then the result is 4 
what role does the int plays here

Comment: The result you get is dependant on system you use, for example for me `sizeof(int)=4` where `sizeof(int*)=8`, address has different size than actual int in the memory, there comes the need of casting